# Why sum of all process CPU(%) is greater than total cpu(%) utilisation in top command

Tags: cpu, process, monitoring, top

In a top command instance, the CPU utilisation (100-idle) was 14% but the top most process "Chrome" alone consumes 253%. I am unsure of how the chrome process consumes CPU more than 100%.

Some answers show that its because of multicore system and we should turn off IRIX mode for that.

If thats right, I want a **solution to turn off IRIX mode in batch mode** since my task relies on running top in batch mode. Else **can I manually divide each process CPU % by no of cores myself**? will the answer same as tunring off IRIX mode.

Comment: You asked this already, and I provided a detailed answer.. maybe edit your original question to include operation in batch mode.

Comment: @ArturMeinild No I have also asks for a command line way to turn off IRIX mode and want to know about manually dividing the cpu% directly by cores. Understand the question and remove the downvote

Comment: I added details on how to disable Irix mode for batch operation both here, and in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to disable Irix mode for top in batch mode:

1. Run `top` in normal mode
2. Disable Irix mode with: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
3. Save a configuration file for the current user: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

The configuration file will be located at `$HOME/.config/procps`

Now, when you run top for this user (including batch mode), Irix mode will be disabled by default.

To make this the default for the `root` user, switch to root (with `sudo -s`) and run the 3 steps above.

*Since top is a relatively simple program, it's not possible to run with a custom config file. If you require custom config or CPU metrics, consider using another method than top output.*

Comment: thought of this solution too. In my case, I cant change the behaviour of top completely. It will help If the configuration file can be given as input in batch mode as I can checkin that file in my project. I want the usual top left undisturbed and "IRIX mode" less top as another version

Comment: Can I manually divide the cpu% of each process with no of cores? Is that same as solaris mode?

Comment: Yes I should believe so. However, the rounding will be a little different, but more or less the same yes.

Comment: Can we make top command use different configuration file located in diferent location. I want to give the path as a param or by any ways

Comment: I am confused now. If a prcoess shows cpu% as 40% it means its (40/16)  % on a 16core server? Does a process spawn all the core +/- equally all the time?

Comment: Please - this is not a discussion forum... 

Comment: Then how can I arrive answer for my question, You skipped a part of the question hence I asked and you are makring question as duplicate and prevent me from asking others too

Comment: I elaborated on the current limitations of top. Maybe you should consider another alternative to top.