# How to manually give configuration file to top command?

Tags: monitoring, top

I know that top behaviour can be changed interactively and can be stored as a cfg file as toprc and it will use that cfg automatically. Is there a way to write and feed the configuration file (stored in different location) to top command as command line or by any ways.

In my case, I have to use a configuration file stored in my project directories and it shouldnt affect normal top behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [my other answer to your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460240/why-sum-of-all-process-cpu-is-greater-than-total-cpu-utilisation-in-top-co/), this is not possible with the current version of top.